# calculate online duration SQL with device online offline events

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have a table that records the devices' online and offline events.
here's an example of a ClickHouse table

```sql
CREATE TABLE device_events
(
    `device_id` String,
    `event_datetime` DateTime,
    `event_type` Enum8('disconnected' = 0, 'connected' = 1)
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
ORDER BY (device_id, event_datetime)
```

Based on this table, I want to calculate the devices' online time every 10 minutes for any given time period. Can this be done with SQL ?

Here is some example data. a device might be online for a very long time.

```sql
INSERT INTO device_events (device_id, event_datetime, event_type) VALUES
('device_1', '2024-02-28 08:01:00', 'connected'),
('device_1', '2024-02-28 09:30:00', 'disconnected'),
('device_1', '2024-02-28 11:00:00', 'connected'),
('device_1', '2024-02-28 11:05:00', 'disconnected'),
('device_1', '2024-02-28 20:00:00', 'connected'),
('device_2', '2024-02-28 08:30:00', 'connected'),
('device_2', '2024-02-28 10:30:00', 'disconnected'),
('device_2', '2024-02-28 12:00:00', 'connected'),
('device_2', '2024-02-28 12:30:00', 'disconnected'),
('device_3', '2024-02-28 07:00:00', 'connected'),
('device_3', '2024-02-28 08:15:00', 'disconnected'),
('device_3', '2024-02-28 14:00:00', 'connected'),
('device_3', '2024-02-28 18:00:00', 'disconnected');
```

Comment: Please do not add random product tags to your question!

Comment: @xren can you provide sample data?

Comment: @Raptor sure, data is updated

Comment: the data does not match your schema.

Comment: @Raptor updated again, all sql tested and worked

Comment: Please, edit your question with the exact desired result on this data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH
  '2024-02-28 08:00:00'::DateTime as dt_start
, '2024-02-28 09:00:00'::DateTime as dt_end
, 10 as min_intl
SELECT
  i.t, e.event_type, count() as cnt
FROM 
(
  -- Table of DateTimes starting from dt_start, ending to dt_end every min_intl minutes
  SELECT 
    dt_start + interval min_intl * arrayJoin(range(intDiv(dt_end - dt_start, 60 * min_intl) + 1)) minute
    as t
) i
, 
(
SELECT 
  *
  -- next event_datetime for this device
, coalesce
  (
      any (cast (event_datetime as Nullable(DateTime))) 
      over (partition by device_id order by event_datetime rows between 1 following and 1 following)
    , '2106-02-07'::DateTime
  )
  as event_datetime_next
FROM 
VALUES
(
('device_id String, event_datetime DateTime, event_type Enum8(''disconnected'' = 0, ''connected'' = 1)'),
('device_1', '2024-02-28 08:01:00', 'connected'),
('device_1', '2024-02-28 09:30:00', 'disconnected'),
('device_1', '2024-02-28 11:00:00', 'connected'),
('device_1', '2024-02-28 11:05:00', 'disconnected'),
('device_1', '2024-02-28 20:00:00', 'connected'),
('device_2', '2024-02-28 08:30:00', 'connected'),
('device_2', '2024-02-28 10:30:00', 'disconnected'),
('device_2', '2024-02-28 12:00:00', 'connected'),
('device_2', '2024-02-28 12:30:00', 'disconnected'),
('device_3', '2024-02-28 07:00:00', 'connected'),
('device_3', '2024-02-28 08:15:00', 'disconnected'),
('device_3', '2024-02-28 14:00:00', 'connected'),
('device_3', '2024-02-28 18:00:00', 'disconnected')
)
device_events
) e
WHERE i.t >= e.event_datetime and i.t < e.event_datetime_next
GROUP BY i.t, e.event_type
ORDER BY i.t, e.event_type
Format PrettyCompact
```

The result is:

```
+-------------------t-+-event_type---+-cnt-+
| 2024-02-28 08:00:00 | connected    |   1 |
| 2024-02-28 08:10:00 | connected    |   2 |
| 2024-02-28 08:20:00 | disconnected |   1 |
| 2024-02-28 08:20:00 | connected    |   1 |
| 2024-02-28 08:30:00 | disconnected |   1 |
| 2024-02-28 08:30:00 | connected    |   2 |
| 2024-02-28 08:40:00 | disconnected |   1 |
| 2024-02-28 08:40:00 | connected    |   2 |
| 2024-02-28 08:50:00 | disconnected |   1 |
| 2024-02-28 08:50:00 | connected    |   2 |
| 2024-02-28 09:00:00 | disconnected |   1 |
| 2024-02-28 09:00:00 | connected    |   2 |
+---------------------+--------------+-----+
```

[fiddle](https://fiddle.clickhouse.com/1b0485a5-6694-460d-a629-628e30aadda8)